# MapStyleSheet properties not applying

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-maps

I'm having problems trying to apply changes to the default MapControls appearances using MapStyleSheets.

Most of the changes I have made have applied OK, but some of the properties have not. I'm using [Map style sheet reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/elements-of-map-style-sheet#settings) and I also use the Map Style Sheet Editor to help me visualizing all the changes before using in my application.

The properties that I'm having problems are:

- **shadedReliefDarkColor**
- **shadedReliefLightColor**

Both are not visible nor usable at the Map Style Sheet Editor, but they appear in the reference page.

Here is the text abot them in the reference:

```
shadedReliefVisible     Bool    ✔   ✔   ✔   ✔   ✔   A flag that indicates whether or not to draw elevation shading on the map.
shadedReliefDarkColor   Color   ✔   ✔   ✔   ✔   ✔   The color of the dark-side of shaded relief. Alpha channel represents the maximum alpha value.
shadedReliefLightColor  Color   ✔   ✔   ✔   ✔   ✔   The color of the light-side of shaded relief. Alpha channel represents the maximum alpha value.
```

My target version is Windows 10 version 1803 (10.0 compilation 17134), both for target and the minimun. If reference is correct, both properties are supported at this version (first check). And here is part of the mssjson file that I read from the file to apply the style sheet. As I said before, the other properties and changes are applyed, but not the two I'm asking about.

```
    {
    "version": "1.*",
  "settings": {
    "atmosphereVisible": true,
    "fogColor": "#6E777872",
    "landColor": "#FFE8E4DF",
    "shadedReliefVisible": true,
    "shadedReliefLightColor": "#FFC8C8C8",
    "shadedReliefDarkColor": "#FF2B2B2B",
    "spaceColor": "#8C06136E"
  },
```

Any idea why I'm having these problems?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I could reproduce your issue that `shadedReliefVisible` works but      shadedReliefLightColor  and shadedReliefDarkColor    are not effect, I will report it to related team.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a documentation bug. Those properties are not currently supported, but were placeholders for a possible future feature. We'll submit a documentation update request.